Error when calling ".length" method on instance variable
I made a quite simple class (boils down to a guessing game) and when I tried to run my code a "error: cannot find symbol" keeps popping up whenever I call the ".length" method on my instance variable.
instance variable:
 private String word;

methods where the error keeps appearing:
private String inWord(String str, int index)
{
        if(str.equals(word.substring(index, index + 1)))
            return str;
        else
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < word.length; i++)
            {
                if(i != index && str.equals(word.substring(i, i + 1)))
                    return "+";
            }
        }
        return "*";
}
    
public String getHint(String str)
{
        String hint = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length; i++)
        {
            hint += inWord(str.substring(i, i + 1), i);
        }
        return hint;
}

in both for loops this error keeps appearing and I am not quite sure what approach I can apply to fix this

length is a method, not a property, so word.length()

oh yea looks like I mixed up the array and string method, either way thanks for the help code works like intended now.

Side note: it’s preferable to use regionMatches instead of combining substring and equals. Or, when the strings only have a single character, like in your case, use charAt(i) instead of substring(i, i + 1) and compare the chars with ==.

You are trying to get the String length by using word.length, which is asking the JVM the property named "length" of the String, which is not public. You want to call word.length() which is a method and does exactly what you need.
Also, I reccomend using a proper debugger.

"Also, I reccomend using a proper debugger." That would probably be for the best, I am just using an online compiler to run this code

You can just install a JDK version and VSCode with the Java extension. Or even IntelliJ, Eclipse or NetBeansz but I find them too complex. Just personal preference.

Length is a method of a String class. So proper syntax should be like this word.length() to get the length of a string

I see... I sort of mixed up the string and array method for finding length, anyways thanks for the help!

You forgot ().
You have to call length().
